# Nginx load balance with upstream SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl

Trying to setup Nginx as load balancer for https servers. The upstream serves over port 443 with SSL certificates configured. How to configure Nginx, so that the SSL certificate configuration is handled only on the upstream servers and not in the Nginx server?

Comment: Could you please post the configuration which solved it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use [Upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html), and [Reverse Proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html). To reverse proxy to the https upstream, use this

```
proxy_pass  https://backend;
```

where backend is an uptream block.

However, if I were doing this, I'd terminate ssl on the nginx server, and make upstream app servers doing what they are good at: serving the content, instead of worrying about ssl encryption/decryption overhead. Setting up ssl termination on nginx is also very simple using the [SSL module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html). A very good case study is also given [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/SSL-Offloader).

Comment: Any sample configuration? I'm getting "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long" to browser and nothing in NGINX error log.

Comment: Does this SO answer fix your problem? http://serverfault.com/questions/497430/error-code-ssl-error-rx-record-too-long

Comment: No, I have tried that. The config file in that sample defines SSL certificates which I'm not doing (because there are none on the NGINX server).

Comment: Is the upstream module also necessary when not trying to load balance, but purely proxying to one backend? Can I simply spell out `proxy_pass https://example.com`?

Comment: OP is asking for _"...not on the Nginx server"_, thus what he wants is *SSL pass-through*; you are suggesting _upstream SSL reverse-proxying_; where'd have to setup SSL certificates on Nginx as well.

Answer (score 5):

seems now possible according to https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-upstreams/ (1.9.4+)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood from [reading relevant discussion](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,234641,234641) on Nginx forum, this is not possible because Nginx needs to terminate upstream SSL connection anyway. If you insist on using Nginx you're left only to replicate SSL configuration and make certificates and key available to Nginx.

The discussion I linked concluded that HAProxy is much better tool for SSL upstream passthrough. Here's [relevant post](https://scriptthe.net/2015/02/08/pass-through-ssl-with-haproxy/) I've found about configuring HAProxy for such purpose. Because I have zero HAProxy experience I can't summarise its configuration or general viability of the solution leaving it to the reader.

## Update

Since 1.9.2 Nginx supports HAProxy's [proxy protocol](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt).