# How to pass a client certificate through two server nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, client-certificates

I have some reason to use two nginx servers before the application server.
Both nginx servers using an SSL connection. 
`Nginx1 (SSL 443 and ssl_verify_client on) -> Nginx2 (SSL 443) -> App (9000)`.

On the first Nginx1 server I use the option: `proxy_set_header client_cert $ssl_client_cert;`
On the second server Nginx2  I use the option: `underscores_in_headers on;`

The problem is that the second Nginx2 server is sent only the first line of the certificate - "----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----".

How to pass a client certificate to the application server?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx terminates SSL with no exception, so if you want this config anyway - you  will need to have SSL config again and keep certificates on the server (here is [relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400260/3961156)) or based on [Nginx support discussion](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,234641,234650#msg-234650) to use HAProxy in TCP mode. Here is the [sample configuration](https://scriptthe.net/2015/02/08/pass-through-ssl-with-haproxy/) article.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I found the solution, and described it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Workaround for proxy client certificate

```
# NGINX1
...
map $ssl_client_raw_cert $a {
    "~^(-.*-\n)(?<1st>[^\n]+)\n((?<b>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<c>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<d>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<e>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<f>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<g>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<h>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<i>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<j>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<k>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<l>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<m>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<n>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<o>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<p>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<q>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<r>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<s>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<t>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<v>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<u>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<w>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<x>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<y>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<z>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ab>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ac>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ad>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ae>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<af>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ag>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ah>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ai>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<aj>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ak>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<al>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<am>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<an>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ao>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ap>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<aq>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ar>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<as>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<at>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<av>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<au>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<aw>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ax>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<ay>[^\n]+)\n)?((?<az>[^\n]+)\n)*(-.*-)$"
    $1st;
}
server {
...
  location  / {
  ...
    proxy_set_header client_cert $a$b$c$d$e$f$g$h$i$j$k$l$m$n$o$p$q$r$s$t$v$u$w$x$y$z$ab$ac$ad$ae$af$ag$ah$ai$aj$ak$al$am$an$ao$ap$aq$ar$as$at$av$au$aw$ax$ay$az;
  ...
  }
  ...
}



# NGINX 2

server {
   ...
   underscores_in_headers on;
   ...
   location  / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_pass http://app:9000/;
   }
   ...
}
```